# PHP getting to grips with the strategy pattern

Tags: php, oop

Im wondering if someone could help me out.

I'm researching the strategy pattern at the moment, but im running into some questions.

As an example, I will describe a database backup scheme.

First I create an interface

```
interface DatabaseBackup {
    public function getConnection()
}
```

Then i create the strategy i will use

```
class DatabaseBackupStrategy {
    private $strategy = NULL;

    public function __construct($service) {

        switch ($service) {
            case "mysql":
                $this->strategy = new MYSQLBackup();
                break;
            case "mssql":
                $this->strategy = new MSSQLBackup();
                break;
        }

    }

    public function getConnection()
    {
        return $this->strategy->testConnection();
    }
}
```

The implementations come next

```
class MYSQLBackup implements DatabaseBackup {
    public function getConnection() {
        \\ Code here
    }
}

class MSSQLBackup implements DatabaseBackup {
    public function getConnection() {
        \\ Code here
    }
}
```

and finally, to call it

```
    $service = new DatabaseBackupStrategy($service);
    $service->getConnection();
```

The above is my understanding of how it works.

But, If i ever want to implement methods in the MYSQLBackup or MSSQLBackup classes, i also have to define it in the DatbaseBackupStrategy class as well.

Is this the best way of doing it?

I feel like im doubling up on code having to define the methods firstly in the interface, then the strategy and lastly in the implementations.

Comment: It seems to me from [the basic wikipedia examples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) that you would be better off dropping `DatabaseBackup` and instead declaring `interface DatabaseBackupStrategy` with concretions like `class MYSQLBackup implements DatabaseBackupStrategy` Can you explain why/share how you came to your current *"understanding of how it works"*?

Comment: Hey Jeff, I have been reading about SOLID, and a common phrase im hearing is, 'always code to an interface', this is why i decided to implement the interface this way

Comment: Inject the strategy as a dependency by requiring the interface in the constructor of the class using it, such as `class MyApp(DatabaseBackupStrategy $service){$service->getConnection();}` and then choose your strategy in the application entry point `$app = new MyApp(new MYSQLBackup);`